# Метод не успевает подписаться на событие

Tags: c#, события

Всем, привет! Разбираюсь в событиях C#. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне получить надпись: **"Oh god, already 5!"** и **"Oh god, already Handler_I starting, i'm late!"** после 5-ой итерации метода CounterClass.Counter(), но при этом объявить обработчики события в классе Program? Я так понял подписчики не успевают инициализироваться/подписаться на событие. Код ниже.

З.Ы: Если объявить обработчики в классе Counter, то все работает.

Спасибо!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EventTestApp
{
    public delegate void MyDelegate();
    class MyEventClass
    {        
        public event MyDelegate MyEvent = delegate { };

        public void OnMyEvent()
        {
            MyEvent.Invoke();
        }
    }

    class CounterClass
    {
        MyEventClass myEventClass = new MyEventClass();
        public void Counter(int i)
        {

            for (; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("In current time i = {0}", i);

                if (i == 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Generate event");
                    myEventClass.OnMyEvent();
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            MyEventClass myEventClass = new MyEventClass();
            CounterClass counter = new CounterClass();

            myEventClass.MyEvent += Handler_I;
            myEventClass.MyEvent += Handler_II;

            //myEventClass.OnMyEvent();
            counter.Counter(0);
            Console.ReadKey();         
        }

        private static void Handler_I()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Oh god, already 5!");
        }

        private static void Handler_II()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Oh god, already Handler_I starting, i'm late!");
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас в `CounterClass` свой экземпляр `MyEventClass myEventClass`, а в `Main()` свой. Надо сделать передачу экземпляра
в  `CounterClass` через его конструктор.

Comment: Действительно! Спасибо большое!